# CentOS 7: hot to increase the boot partition followed by logical volumes?

Tags: centos, partition

On a CentOS 7 server I'm almost out of space on the `/boot` partition and I need to increase its space.

It is followed by a logical volume, as shown below:

**df -h**

```
# df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_sys-lv_root   70G  8.1G   59G  13% /
devtmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       3.9G  368M  3.5G  10% /run
tmpfs                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   190M  147M   30M  84% /boot
tmpfs                       783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/0
```

**lsblk**

```
# lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                  2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda                  8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0 99.8G  0 part
  ├─vg_sys-lv_root 253:0    0   71G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg_sys-lv_swap 253:1    0    8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                 11:0    1  4.2G  0 rom
```

**fdisk -l**

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c4b14

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      411647      204800   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          411648   209715199   104651776   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_sys-lv_root: 76.2 GB, 76235669504 bytes, 148897792 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_sys-lv_swap: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

As for what I could understand, the logical volumes are the result of the **docker** installation (not running now).

Comment: Hmm. it doesn't look like your LVM setup has anything to do with Docker; You've got logical volumes for your root fs and swap, so you can't simply remove LVM. However, GRUB2 can boot from an LVM logical volume. So if you have space in your LVM volume group, or can create the space, you can carefully migrate `/boot` to a logical volume. You can then reclaim some of the 200MB by turning the partition into a physical volume and adding it to your volume group.

Comment: ok, so the only option I will have is to migrate my boot partition to a logical volume? How can I do this?

Comment: Apparently gparted has features to move a partition: https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions I don't know if it supports this when there's LVM (you'd probably have to pre-shrink a few things first if it doesn't, using lvm commands). They also warn about risk and that a backup should be done first. Anyway this would be possible only running from an other system (eg: booting with a live usb and running it from there). As this might be too complex, consider Emmanuel's option or simply reinstalling